# Why my console.log is showing 'Undefined' first And Then Display The required number even after i log it after a settimeout of 2 sec {REACT}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending AllmightyUID = 2(for example) from App.js in the User.js component through contextApi ,there is no useEffect in my User component , but when i log the value in my User component it is logged 2 times first time is shows undefined and second time correct data(2) even if i log it after 2- 3 seconds due to this i am unable to make further api calls (i get cannot read the value undefined errors)

solutions i have tried :-

1.) I have removed strict mode from index.js 
2.) passed the value as props but still the same  problem

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { AllMightyUID } from '../App'
import axios from 'axios'


const User = (props) => {
  
  let receivedUID = useContext(AllMightyUID)
  
  const [UID1, setUID1] = useState();
  

  setTimeout(() => {
     
    console.log(receivedUID);

  }, 2000);

  return(
    <></>
  )
}
```

I am sending data from a state variable in App.js

Answer (score 0):

Often, API calls are asynchronous by nature, meaning the rest of the code can execute while the app is still waiting for the API response. Which explains why you get the value when you use the `setTimeout` function.

You can try to have an if statement that will make other API calls after the UID has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering it's called that's why you got the error.

You should try to in `useEffect` and then you solved your issue.

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AllMightyUID } from '../App'
import axios from 'axios'

const User = (props) => {

 let receivedUID = useContext(AllMightyUID)
 const [UID1, setUID1] = useState();
  
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(receivedUID);
 }, []);     

 return(
   <></>
 )
}
```